# Bash removing duplicate in a string list of argument $@

Tags: bash, duplicates

In an bash shell script I am receiving a list of argument in $@ which are : a b c d a c e
Depending of the argument I need to do something specific with a case structure.
But I only want to do it for a b c d e

I should only use bash and not any other language...I can use awk for example

```
for argument in "$@"
do
    case $argument in
a)
.....
```

Have tried many things but without success

Any help much appreciated

Comment: BTW, it's always better to show a specific thing you tried instead of just saying "many things". (Maybe show one, and describe a few of the others briefly --  knowing what you tried gives us a lot of context to use in building better answers).

Answer (score 5):

Use an associative array to track arguments you've already seen. Note that this requires bash 4.0 or later; the 3.2.x release that Apple ships is too old, as it only supports numerically-indexed arrays (`declare -a`, but not `declare -A`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A seen=( )
declare -a deduped=( )

for arg in "$@"; do                # iterate over our argument list
  [[ ${seen[$arg]} ]] && continue  # already seen this? skip it
  seen[$arg]=1                     # mark as seen going forward...
  deduped+=( "$arg" )              # ...and add to our new/future argv
done

set -- "${deduped[@]}"  # replace "$@" with contents of deduped array
```

Comment: If you are not concerned about the order in which the args are seen, instead of using a separate array `deduped`, you can set argv from the keys of `seen` with `set -- "${!seen[@]}"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could print, then sort unique, then print quoted the list and re-eval into arguments. With GNU tools:

```
set -- a b c d a c e
tmp=$(printf "%s\0" "$@" | sort -uz | xargs -0 printf "%q ")
eval set -- "$tmp"
```

Comment: If `xargs` calls `/usr/bin/printf`, it isn't guaranteed to support `%q`; that's specific to the shell-builtin printf in bash and ksh (unless it's a recent coreutils addition and I haven't been keeping up, but even then that would be GNU-centric).

Comment: ...to be clear, I don't think this is a bad approach in general; if you did `arr=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do arr+=( "$item" ); done < <(printf '%s\0' "$@" | sort -uz); set -- "${arr[@]}"`, that should work.

Comment: (Also as a rule, I always recommend `eval "set -- $tmp"` over `eval set -- "$tmp"` just for the sake of being more clear to the code's readers about how `eval` works, even though they're functionally identical in present circumstances).